# What's the proper way to upload another web folder into Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I use Wordpress for my blog and currently has a project which has a web folder that contains **HTML/CSS/JS/PHP** (basic website from scratching).

I can run it using MAMP by `localhost/project/index.html` and want to add the whold website into my Wordpress blog as a seperate page like `mywebsite.com/project/index.html`.

What's the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way, is to get a separate domain or create a subdomain for that second site..

However, it should be possible to just create a folder in the root of your existing domain, and upload the files into it..

If its meant to be a part of the existing website, the proper way would be to create a separate template for that page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates